# How to call db function inside a package using apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a package `pkg_multi_parm_price_agg` in oracle db which has a function

```
 FUNCTION FN_GET_GROUP_ID_WRAPPER_F(PI_PARM_CODE_VAL_STR IN VARCHAR2,
                                     PI_PARM_COUNT        IN NUMBER)
    RETURN TXN_DTL_PRITM.PRICEITEM_PARM_GRP_ID%TYPE;
```

currently iusing JDBC prepared statement i am able to call it successfully in my java project using below query and providing required parameters :

```
SELECT pkg_multi_parm_price_agg.fn_get_group_id_wrapper_F(?,?) FROM DUAL;
```

I want to understand if same can be called using Apache spark using **Java**?

**EDIT** - This question is regarding calling a DB function using Java using apache spark functionality.Hence I consider it as different question, kindly correct my understanding if otherwise.

Comment: @user8371915 here i am calling a function , can you please help me understand how is it duplicate?

Comment: To execute arbitrary statement against the database. This has to be done by providing a query as a reader argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
  val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)
  import sqlContext.implicits._

  val jdbcHostname = "localhost"
  val jdbcPort = 3306
  val jdbcDatabase = "test"
  val jdbcUsername = "root"
  val jdbcPassword = "password"
  val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:mysql://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort}/${jdbcDatabase}?user=${jdbcUsername}&password=${jdbcPassword}"

  val query = """( select query ) foo"""

  val df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    .option("url", jdbcUrl)
    .option("useUnicode", "true")
    .option("continueBatchOnError", "true")
    .option("dbtable", query).option("user", jdbcUsername)
    .option("password", jdbcPassword)
    .load()
```

replace `select query` with your query. It will give you dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for your response ...I forget to mention that i need to write same in java.

Comment: Also how to provide paramters which is ?,? in my query?